# How to get multiple counts from the comparison of tow tables(in a database) based on specific key values

Tags: php, mysql

this is my 1st post so excuse me if my question is a bit weird. I work on a test project for an android application that send some data to a server. The java part is already done but I don't have much knowledge on serverside things and databases.So I need to find a way to compare two tables. A small one and a much bigger. For example,the small one is a list of a company's employees and the bigger is a database of companies and their employees. I need to make an array with the counts of the similar rows from the comparison of the two tables. I know my English are a bit rusty so I will try to be more clear:

company x:

```
|id  |emp_name|age|
|2314|bob     |33 |
|2314|sam     |45 |
|2314|paul    |28 |
```

companies database:

```
|id  |emp_name|age|
|1342|nick    |33 |
|1342|helen   |38 |
|1342|john    |52 |
|...              |
|6742|bob     |33 |
|6742|julia   |36 |
|6742|paul    |28 |
|...              |
|7654|sam     |45 |
|6742|bob     |33 |
|6742|paul    |28 |
|...              |
```

so for the above example I need to make an array like this:

```
|0|2|3|.....|
```

I don't care about the company id, just for names and age.

Comment: Can you explain how `|0|2|3|.....| ` is generated from the database table? What do those number represent?

Comment: whats the relationship between the two tables ? what is the definition of similarity, is the name considered as a similar row ?

Comment: well I use php and MySQL to search in the table.The array is generated from the database.With similar row I mean having the same name and age.In my example the id represent the different companies.I want to count how many employees with equal(equal to my small table)names and ages exist in every company.So these values are stored in a php array.And these values are the "how many similar rows exist in every company in the database"(similar to my small table)...Sorry I cant explain it with any other way,maybe this cant be done the way I think.If you can suggest any other way it would be good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an aggregate SQL query to count the matching companies between both tables. Then, have PHP run the query using its [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or other database API into an associative array and/or designate a separate array and append query counts into it:

**SQL** Query

```
  SELECT s.emp_name, s.age
         COUNT(*) As emp_count
    FROM smalltable s
   INNER JOIN largetable l
      ON s.emp_name = l.emp_name
     AND s.age = l.age
GROUP BY s.emp_name, s.age
```

**PHP** Script

```
try {
    // OPEN CONNECTION
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);    
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT s.emp_name, s.age
                   COUNT(*) As emp_count
            FROM smalltable s
            INNER JOIN largetable l
            ON s.emp_name = l.emp_name
            AND s.age = l.age
            GROUP BY s.emp_name, s.age";

    // QUERY AND FETCH RESULTS
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$values = [];
// ITERATE THROUGH ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY, $row
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
      $values[] = $row['emp_count'];  // APPEND emp_count TO $values ARRAY
      echo $row['emp_count'];         // ECHO emp_count
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
$dbh = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
$arr=array(0=> array("id"=>'1', "emp_name"=>"bob", "age"=>33),1=> array("id"=>'2', "emp_name"=>"sam", "age"=>45),2=> array("id"=>'3', "emp_name"=>"paul", "age"=>   28));
$company=array(0=> array("id"=>'1', "emp_name"=>"bob", "age"=>33),1=> array("id"=>'2', "emp_name"=>"samd", "age"=>45),2=> array("id"=>'3', "emp_name"=>"paul", "age"=>  28),3=> array("id"=>'1', "emp_name"=>"bobe", "age"=>33),4=> array("id"=>'2', "emp_name"=>"same", "age"=>45),5=> array("id"=>'3', "emp_name"=>"paul", "age"=>    28),6=> array("id"=>'1', "emp_name"=>"bob", "age"=>33),7=> array("id"=>'2', "emp_name"=>"sam", "age"=>45),8=> array("id"=>'3', "emp_name"=>"paul", "age"=>  28));


$result=array();


foreach($arr as $ar1){
  $i=0;
  foreach($ar1 as $ar2key=>$ar2val){

    foreach($company as $comp1){
      foreach($comp1 as $comp2key=>$comp2val){
        if($ar1["emp_name"]==$comp1[$comp2key]){
           $i+=1;   
           $result[$comp2val]=$i;

         }
      }    
    } 
  }
}

print_r($result);
//$result=array_values($result);
//print_r($result);
```

Comment: sorry if I were not so clear, but the database already exists,so I just need to compare the two sql tables.